# Python C Extension OpenMP

Tags: python, parallel-processing, openmp, gil, python-extensions

i am getting a segmentation violation in the python interpreter when trying to access a variable which is returned by my own OpenMP C++ extension.

All the solutions which i have found are either using ctypes or cython (which i cannot use). http://snatverk.blogspot.de/2012/03/c-parallel-modules-for-python.html shows a small example of a OpenMP enabled python extension. Although i tried to implement my for loops like in the example, it still does not work.

My Code extension code function looks like this:

```
static PyObject *
matcher_match(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{

if(PyTuple_Size(args) != 2)
{
    return NULL;
}

PyObject *names = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 0);
Py_ssize_t namesSize = PyList_Size(names);

PyObject *namesB = PyTuple_GetItem(args, 1);
Py_ssize_t namesBSize = PyList_Size(namesB);

PyObject *matchIdcs = PyList_New(namesSize);

Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS;

int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i, j)
for(i = 0; i < namesSize; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < namesBSize; j++)
    {
        // test_pair_ij is a pure C function without callbacks into python
        // it only uses the C++ STL like std::vector
        float a = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(names, i));
        float b = PyFloat_AsDouble(PyList_GetItem(namesB, j));
        bool res = test_pair_ij(a, b)
        PyObject *matchVal;
        if(res)
        {
            matchVal = Py_BuildValue("i", j);
        }
        else
        {
            matchVal = Py_BuildValue("i", -1);
        }
        PyList_SetItem(matchIdcs, i, matchVal);
    }
}
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS;

return matchIdcs;
}
```

The function matcher_match() receives two lists, names and namesB.
I check every combination of names and namesB (their float attributes) for a specific condition which is indicated by the function test_pair_ij(). The function is a pure C(++) implementation which does not callback into python.

The C extension is called with:

```
from matcher import match
# some random lists for this example
names = ['123', '231', ...]
namesB = ['342', ...]
matchResult = match(names, namesB)
import pandas as pd
mr = pd.Series(matchResult)
mr.to_csv('matchResult.csv')
```

When the lists names and namesB are rather small, the code is running ok. But with larger lists, i cannot access matchResult anymore in the python code. When i try to, i get a  segmentation violation (which is inside the python interpreter i guess). I have recompiled the C extension without openmp and it ran ok again, even with the larger lists.

I guess the problem is some messup in the memory of the python variables which i access from my extension. This may have to do with the GIL, although i am releasing and acquiring it. Do i need to make any more variables private in this case?
Any other ideas on this?

**EDIT**: fixed calling arguments of function test_pair_ij.

**EDIT 2**: fixed code of storing matchIdcs

**ANSWER**:

the code was releasing the GIL and the call to **PyList_SetItem(matchIdcs, i, matchVal);** was modifying a python structure, which is not allowed (see http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#releasing-the-gil).

Comment: `names[i]` - what do you expect this to do? It's not doing what you think it does. In particular, it doesn't do list indexing. Instead, it interprets `names` as a pointer into an array and does `*(names + i)`.

Comment: Same with `matchIdcs`. It's also weird that the values from most iterations of the inner loop get discarded.

Comment: Sorry for the messup. I fixed that too.